# Why am I getting an "undefined index" error when defining a session?

Tags: php

I am new to PHP and sessions so go easy on me.
This is my code

```
if(isset($_POST["username"]) || isset($_SESSION["username"])){
   $_SESSION["username"] = $_POST["username"];
   echo $_SESSION["username"];
   } else {
     exit();
   }
```

I'm getting an undefined index in the line that is supposed to define $SESSION["username"]. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you called **session_start();** ?

Comment: btw on your if condition you are verifying that one or **||** the other is set, if you want them to be set you have to change it to **and** or **&&**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. The problem occurs if isset($_POST["username"]) is false. Then when $_POST["username"] doesn't exist so it returns an error

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
if(isset($_POST["username"])){
 $_SESSION["username"] = $_POST["username"];
 echo $_SESSION["username"];
} else if (isset($_SESSION["username"])) {
 echo $_SESSION["username"];
} else {
 exit();
}
```

you're checking if your `$_POST` variable is set or `$_SESSION` variable is set, so what's happening here is your `if` statement is returning true because your `$_SESSION` variable is already set.
And don't forget to start your session using `session_start()`